# I want to show that $fh \in \mathcal L^{1}(\mu)$ and conclude whether $fh \in \mathcal L^{1}(\mu)$ holds (generally) for $f,h \in \mathcal L^{1}(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal E, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $f,g,h$ be functions from $\mathcal M(\mathcal E)$ (set of $\mathcal E - \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ measurable functions).

Suppose $h \in \mathcal L^{1}(\mu)$ (set of Lebesgue integrable functions s.t both the integral of negative and positive parts is less than infinity) and there exist a positive constant $K$ s.t $|f| \le K$ for $\mu$-almost-everywhere.

> I want to show that $fh \in \mathcal L^{1}(\mu)$ and conclude whether $fh \in \mathcal L^{1}(\mu)$ holds (generally) for $f,h \in \mathcal L^{1}(\mu)$

Since $h \in \mathcal L^{1}(\mu)$ and $f \in \mathcal M (\mathcal E)$ I can conclude that $fh \in \mathcal M (\mathcal E)$. I have tried looking at the integral $$\int fh d \mu = \int (fh)^+ d \mu - \int (fh)^- d \mu$$, but I can't conclude anything from this.

Comment: **Hint:** $|fh|\le K|h|$.

Comment: How can I apply this ?

Comment: $K|h|$ is integrable. Any measurable function dominated by an integrable function is likewise integrable. It helps tremendously if you know that $|f|=f^++f^-$, and therefore $f$ is integrable iff the integral of $|f|$ is finite.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this.

Comment: To see that the product of $L^1$ functions is not $L^1$ function in general, consider $f(x) =g(x)= \chi_{(0,1)} \cdot x^{-2/3}$.